# How to set up Accept-Encoding to gzip in Python client?

Tags: python, http, gzip

This is probably a very newbie question, but I'm reading [HTTP Request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) library and I need to write a code that will make a request to a server and asks for gzip compression (since the server supports gzip compression).

For instance, I have:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('some_url')
r.json()
```

I know it has something to do with sending `Accept-Encoding: gzip` in the header of the HTTP request, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Note that `requests` sets `Accept-Encoding` to "`gzip, deflate`" by default.  Unless you explicitly want *only* gzip, you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to set the header by using the header argument.

```
import requests
headers = {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'}
r = requests.get('some_url',headers=headers)
result = r.json()
```